# Why isn't my sidebar dropping to my footer?

Tags: css, html

I've my sidebar to height of 100% which should drop it to my footer, but this isn't happening it only drops for the amount of text in the sidebar.

My CSS:

```
.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #B5E3FF;
}
```

Why is my sidebar not dropping to my footer?

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ore18kv/

Comment: Look at this article about sticky footer may help you about structure of html: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Comment: @stormie remove the height:100% of html in css. then your sidebar will extend with its content.

Comment: It already sizes according to content, that's the issue. I want it to drop to the footer, which according to @Pik_at's article can be fixed by using `height: auto !important;`

Comment: is that works? with height:auto !important;  or you should use px value for height.

Comment: No, it just fixes the position of my footer which hasn't changed anything now that I've updated the jsfiddle. I think that @Pik_at misread the question

Comment: I guess you should read about `float` and understand what `height: 100%` does and doesn't.

Comment: If you need your sidebar to stick to the footer, put it inside the footer and position it above it using position absolute (an empty absolute positioned div placed at the top of the footer might be needed as a helper container so you can place your sidebar at the bottom of it to make it stick up).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ore18kv/23/ try this. position: fixed may lead an undesired output in future.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ The container text is covered by the sidebar in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stormie, try this

```
.left-sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #B5E3FF;
    left:0px;
}
```

Comment: This works, I was about to comment asking Bondye if using `position` instead of float would work.

Comment: Once I struggled with this on past year, then I find out this :)